# Android : GL error while resizing: 0x506 (ignored)

Tags: android, linux, opengl, android-emulator, android-espresso

I am getting below error continuously when I am using any Android Emulator.

```
"GL error while resizing: 0x506 (ignored)"
```

Do anyone has any idea how to resolve this? Does it can impact my Espresso UI test case as after this I am not able to run my espresso test case. My test cast get stuck as soon as it launch and try to click on a button with following error

```
android.support.test.espresso.AppNotIdleException: Looped for 2 iterations over 60 SECONDS. The following Idle Conditions failed .
```

Comment: I am getting this error as well.

Comment: Any updates? I'm getting same error.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem. I have 1366x768 resolution on my laptop and was using 1080x1920 resolution on Android emulator. Lowering it to 480x800 fixed the GL error spam so I guess that error comes if your screen resolution is smaller than Android emulator resolution.

Answer (score 3):

Increasing the size of the emulator window stopped the error printouts for me. (drag a corner of the emulator).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem using this setting

[image]